# What is going to happen in this situation?

Tags: united-states, banking, deposits, stimulus

My boyfriend's stimulus check came and I did a mobile deposit into my Wells Fargo account without having him endorse it. I  understand what I did wrong and I know how to prevent problems in the future.

I have no idea how this works. For now, what can I expect? Are they going to take the money back (obviously temporarily)? How long will it take?

Comment: Have you contacted Wells Fargo?

Comment: Do you have a joint account? Does he know what you did?